# Issue in creating pdf using fileFactory->create() in magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, pdf

I am pulling files from 3rd party server using apis and generating pdf files.

My code is some thing like this. I Will update the sample code to explain my approach.

```
foreach ($fileData['dataDocuments']['items'] as $document) {
    //API Call
    $urlToGetData = $this->api->getDocumentById($identifier, $docId);
    $data = $this->api->getDataFromApi($urlToGetData);
    $decodeData = json_decode($data, true);
    $labelContent[] = base64_decode((string)$imageString, true); //you can add more image strings.

    //use Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping\LabelGenerator;
    $outputPdf = $this->labelGenarator->combineLabelsPdf($labelContent);

    try{
        $this->fileFactory->create(
            $docId,
            $outputPdf->render(),
            \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/pdf'
        );
     }catch(\Exception $e){
        $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
     }
}
```

While running through the loop ( I have pulling like 6 files from server using api) only first two files are generating and getting an error on  `$this->fileFactory->create()`

I am not getting any exception also, Any hint to generate all files together here. If i run this for each and every file individually i can generate 6 files without no any issue. But my requirement is download all files at once. Any guess or suggestion to fix this issue highly appreciated.